# 'publish' property in serverless config

Tags: serverless

In legacy AWS Lambda node.js project there is a `publish` property in `serverless.yml`.

```yaml
service:
  name: service-name
  publish: false
```

I didn't pay attention to it before, but after upgrading `serverless` to v.2.0.0 I get the warning on `serverless deploy`:

```
Serverless: Configuration warning at 'service': unrecognized property 'publish'
```

It seems this property has become deprecated, but what did it do? Is it safe to remove it from `serverless.yml`?